# When to us DAO / Repository and when to use Inversion of Control?

Tags: php, oop, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, dao

**Purpose:**

I am seeking to "get data inside my Controller class". There are two approaches I am trying to evaluate.

- injecting a DAO into my Controller - Controller becomes aware of the "foreign" data-providing construct (repository, DAO, model). Controller can query those constructs to receive the data it needs.
- Creating and populating Controller elsewhere - Controller is not cognizant of any "foreign" data-providing construct. It is directly populated by the data it needs.

**Injecting Data Access Object**

I can inject my DAO object into Controller and use it to call various data related to functionality I want to implement.

```
$controller = new Controller(New DAO());
echo $controller->dao->getData();
```

My controller is *aware* of the DAO.

**Creating and Populating Controller Directly**

I can use a Factory Method or Builder pattern or DataMapper and *create & populate* my Controller with the data it needs, without the need of injecting any DAO into the controller itself.

```
//factory
$data = $this->entityManager->getSomeData();
$controller = new Controller();
$controller->setData($data);
echo $controller->getData();
return $controller;
```

Controller is *not aware* of the DAO.  It is just populated with data directly elsewhere.

Which way is recommended for what situation?

Comment: you might want to read [this](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) on the topic you're so interested in